# Where to put $(document).ready in Master page for webform

Tags: javascript, webforms, master-pages

I have this script that I am using to solve the problem in Twitter Bootstrap of not changing the colour of the active `<li>` tab. I am using webforms.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = window.location.pathname;
                var substr = url.split('/');
                var urlaspx = substr[substr.length - 1];
                $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav li a').each(function () {
                    if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Now I am pretty new to both javascript and asp.net. So this may be a bad question, and I apologise in advance, but I would like to know the proper place to put this.

I originally had placed it in the `<head>` tags on the Site.Master page. But it didn't work. Also, when I added it to the custom.js file, that is called in the body, I have created it also does not work. So I have just added the script itself to the body, this works, but something tells me this is not the 'best practise' way of doing it and was hoping someone with more experience can tell me where it should go, and why.

Here is a copy of the Master.Site page and the locations I have tried.

```
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="~/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <%--Custom CSS created for site--%>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <%--Custom JS created for site--%>
        <script src="Scripts/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <%-- This does nt work inside the custom.js --%>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = window.location.pathname;
                var substr = url.split('/');
                var urlaspx = substr[substr.length - 1];
                $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav li a').each(function () {
                    if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Not sure about your problem but when I try to incorporate javascript file on master page, it seems like the id of items has to be checked carefully. For example, the id of an item on contentplaceholder would be changed to contentPlaceHolderName_id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a js-file, name it 'MyScript.js', and save that in the folder 'Scripts' on your server. Then adding this to your master-page:

```
    <%--Custom JS created for site--%>
    <script src="Scripts/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script><%-- <<< NEW --%>
```

???

Comment: Actually the one above 'custom.js' is exactly what you describe. But if I add that function in that it doesn't run for some reason.

Comment: I see this: `<%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>`... perhaps that will make you wiser :)